# MultilabelBinarizer error when empty class is present

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I'm building a multilabel classifier, when I try to call the classification report I get the following error: `ValueError: All labels must be in [0, n labels) for multilabel targets. Got 6 > 2`, following there's a minimal example that produces the error

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

import pandas as pd

a = [
     [3, 4],
     [6],
     [3],
     [],
     [6, 4]
]
bin = MultiLabelBinarizer()
bin.fit(a)

a = bin.transform(a)
report = classification_report(
    a,
    a, 
    output_dict=True, 
    zero_division=0, 
    labels=bin.classes_
)
print(report)
```

when I try to convert classes to strings I get the following error:  `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`. If I comment out `labels=bin.classes_` everything works, but I'd like to have the original classes in the report. How can I solve it? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

For the classification report, try using the `target_names` argument in place of `labels`:

```
report = classification_report(
    a,
    a, 
    output_dict=True, 
    zero_division=0, 
    target_names=list(map(str, bin.classes_)),
)
print(report)
```

This is suboptimal in the sense that the original integer classes are "stringified" in the report.